How to solve constructor params missing issue?
This is my constructor code for the trading receiver
    constructor(address _staking, address _trading, address _lzEndpoint)
        NonblockingLzApp(_lzEndpoint)
    {
        liquidityI = ILiquidity(_staking);
        tradingI = Itrading(_trading);
    }

I am trying to deploy this contract with hardhat I have written script for it
deployment code goes like this
    const TradingReceiver = await ethers.getContractFactory('tradingReceiver');
    tradingReceiver = await TradingReceiver.deploy(
        liquidity.address,
        trading.address,
        zero.address
    );
    await tradingReceiver.deployed();

But I am getting type error

TypeError: No arguments passed to the base constructor. Specify the arguments or mark "tradingReceiver" as abstract.
--> contracts/Tradingreceiver.sol:14:1:
|
14 | contract tradingReceiver is NonblockingLzApp {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Base constructor parameters:

I am passing the variable trading receiver as well I am passing correct address as well
I don't know why this contract is failing to deploy
Please help if you can
Thank You in advance
Note: I am using a pre-written contract

Hello guys I solved this issue. Contract was using an older version of layerzero npm package so maybe the author did not pass the owner address in the constructor
The issue was in inherited contact used by the NonblockingLzApp contract
Thank You

You could add your comment as answer. That we the question can be marked as resolved.
